# Github Actions Docker Image size

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am building an application where I am using Github Actions to run CICD in which I am building Docker Images and pushing it to my cloud registry.

Unfortunately, the images built through github actions is more than 4 times larger in size than which are built on my local machine.

Here is the snapshot of the cloud registry with same image built in two ways, please look at the size difference for the same code.

[image]

Here is my github actions yaml file looks like:

```
name: Build and Push Summarizer App Docker Image to AWS ECR
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    name: Build Image & Push to ECR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: eu-central-1

    - name: Login to AWS ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, Tag, and Push the Image to AWS ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: summarizer-service
        IMAGE_TAG: latest
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Am I doing something wrong in the GitHub actions? Please help with your valuable suggestions.

My Docker file looks like

```
from python:3.9-slim-buster


run apt-get update
run apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-pip git-all
run apt-get install -y nginx supervisor

run pip3 install uwsgi

run apt-get install -y software-properties-common
run apt-get update
run add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
run apt-get install -y sqlite3


COPY ./requirements.txt /home/docker/
run pip3 install -r /home/docker/requirements.txt

COPY ./nginx-app.conf /home/docker/
COPY ./supervisor-app.conf /home/docker/
COPY ./uwsgi.ini /home/docker/
COPY ./uwsgi_params /home/docker/

COPY ./app /home/docker/app

# setup all the configfiles
run echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
run rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
run ln -s /home/docker/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
run ln -s /home/docker/supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/


expose 80
expose 443
cmd ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

I tried building the docker images via GitHub actions and locally via docker commands. I see a huge size difference and I do not understand the difference.

The contents of the two images look the same.
Below are the screenshots of the Image contents

Github Image contents are as follows:
[image]

Local Image contents are as follows:
[image]

I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: Have you run the two images locally and looked at the contents of the disk to see what the difference is? That would be my first troubleshooting step if I were in your shoes. Like, if the `.git` folder isn't in your `.dockerignore`, are you doing a shallow clone locally and thus have a smaller `.git`? Are you using multi-stage builds?

Comment: The contents of both images look the same. And, I already added .git to .dockerignore as well. 

I am not sure about multi-stage builds.

Comment: What does your `dockerfile` look like?

Comment: @DanielMann Added Dockerfile

Comment: What does `docker images` show locally?

Comment: @Azeem It shows the image size is 3.41GB